# Laravel 5.2 Basic routing from xampp/htdocs does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a home page that is routed and has a blade template. Everything is all fine. But I also have a login page, that I created using the `php artisan make:auth`. It was all working on when I was using the integrated Laravel server, but I had to move my project to xampp's htdocs folder, to make use of the phpmyadmin database management features. So I copied my project over, typed in the new address (was localhost:8000, now it's http://localhost/laravel52/public/), and it worked. Then I tried http://localhost/laravel52/public/login, where my login form was, and I got routed to localhost/login. And that is not valid. Here is my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

Route::auth();
```

The important lines from `AuthController.php`

```
protected $loginPath = '/login';
    protected $redirectPath = '/home';
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

And finally my `AdminController.php` Controller file:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index() {
        return view('admin');
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried setting the `APP_URL=` in the .env file to the current project root e.g. `APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel52/public/` But that did not work.

Comment: Try using http://localhost/laravel52/public/index.php/login

Comment: That works, but the problem is, all my css and js files, located in the public  folder are not being loaded, because their path is set the same way... So all my pages are just html and no styling.

Comment: How you include your css/js in blade.php?

Comment: this format is being used for local files: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
All files are in the public folder.

Comment: Try using: <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to laravel, and I have no idea how to include files or how to point to links. This helps. Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: @MihailIvanchev Check your .htacess workig or not.

Comment: .htaccess is working ok. problem is solved.